# get ArrayList inside another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm getting from a function an ArrayList with the following content:

```
List main = new ArrayList();
List one = new ArrayList();
List two = new ArrayList();
List three = new ArrayList();

main.add(one);
main.add(two);
main.add(three);
```

Now I'm trying to get the elements inside each ArrayList inside main in another function where a parameter is the ArrayList "main":

```
function getMainItems(List main){
    List mainData = new ArrayList();    
    for(int i = 1; i < main.size() ; i++) {
    mainData.clear();
    mainData.addAll((ArrayList) main.get(i));
        for(int j=0;j<mainData.size();j++){
            /* do some stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList"

What am I doing wrong? How should I cast the object from the "main" ArrayList?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't need to cast at all if you use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). You should be doing this anyway: raw types like `new ArrayList()` will give you compiler warnings.

Comment: Can you explain that to me please? I'm kinda new with Java

Comment: In this case, it allows you to specify the type of data your list will be holding. If you just have `List`, all Java knows is that it's a list of "stuff". It could be *anything*: strings, integers, custom objects. Using generics, you can say `List<String>` which is a list of strings. It can only contain strings, and nothing else. You could even say `List<List<String>>` which is a list of lists of strings. There's more to it than that, but that's the gist. There's plenty of material online.

Comment: What does the "function" in your code?

Comment: If you want to learn about generics and why we should use it, read [the following](http://allenlsy.com/NOTES-of-Effective-Java-4/)

Comment: Gets the collection of lists ("main" list), then get each list (main.get(i)) and reads the data of each of it, now I can´t use generics because the lists inside "main" list have different types of information (String,Double,Integer)

Comment: @ManuelVasquezPimentel You can still use generics. You can say `ArrayList<Object>`. Storing multiple different types of information in your list seems like a flaw in your design, however.

Comment: @Michael yeah, I thought about that the other day, and I applied something similar, I review the content of each `ArrayList` and they're returning `Object[]` arrays, so I casted them to object lists and everything worked just well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(ArrayList) main.get(i)`

you're casting the variable itself to an entire ArrayList

Comment: So should I assign the value of the cast to the variable?  `mainData = (ArrayList) main.get(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you know you are only filling the first arraylist with arraylists, then typecast it. `ArrayList<ArrayList> mainArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();`
This helps with getting/setting/evaluating things belonging to the array. It is horrible practice to typecast as you are pulling things or putting things into the array (mentioned above) as this will slow down your code and makes things generally less comprehensible for the next developer.

If i understand correctly you are trying to get all the variables inside an arraylist which contains arraylists into another "flat" arraylist:

```
for (int x = 0; x<main.size();x++)
{
   //here we can access each array list with main.get(x).
   for (int y=0; y<main.get(x).size(); y++)
      //here you can do something with each element inside each nested arraylist : 
      //main.get(x).get(y)

}
```

Comment: Kind of, I want to get the array lists inside of main and do some other process with each arrayList collected

Comment: I can't get `main.get(x).length` because the function `get` returns an object and not the ArrayList

Comment: you should typecast your arraylists then... try replacing List mainData = new ArrayList(); with ArrayList<ArrayList> mainData = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(); then when you do your gets, it will know that the return type of whatever your getting is an arraylist. and i messed up it isnt length its size() for an arraylist.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0; i<main.size(); i++) {
    List list = (List)main.get(i);
    for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(j));
    }
}
```

Comment: `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to List`

Comment: Use this code, type casting is require...

for(int i=0; i<main.size(); i++) {
      List list = (List)main.get(i);
      for(int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {
       System.out.println(list.get(j));
      }
     }